# Animation showing improperly on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an animation shown in the following code snippet.

```js
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.loadclass');
const html = document.querySelector('html')
const cornermenu = document.querySelector('.menu')
const root = document.documentElement
const a = document.querySelectorAll('#adddisp')

logo.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  html.appendChild(logo)
  logo.classList.add('movelogo')
  for (const adddisp of a) {
    adddisp.classList.add('adddisp');
    adddisp.classList.remove('dispnone');
  }
  setTimeout(() => {  button(); }, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => {  cornermenu.classList.add("menuload"); }, 1000);
},
{ once: true }
);

function button() {
  for (const loadclass of buttons) {
    loadclass.classList.add('buttonload');
  }
}

/*/ irrelevant but this logs the ID of the key you pressed
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(key) {
  console.log(key.which)
})
/*/
```

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background-color: black;
}

.break {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 0;
}

.flex {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    resize: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow: visible;
}

.homeflex {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.animate {
    animation: fadein ease 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.logo {
    width: 6vw;
    opacity: 0%;
    animation: load ease 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 250ms;
    min-width: 60px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.movelogo {
    animation: movecorner ease 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes load {
    0%   {width: 0%; opacity: 100%;}
    25%  {width: 30%; border-radius: 50%;}
    50%  {width: 30%; border-radius: 50%;}
    100% {width: 20%; border-radius: 10%; opacity: 100%;}
}

@keyframes movecorner {
    0%   {
        width: 20%;
        border-radius: 10%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        opacity: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        border-radius: 20%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 2%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        opacity: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex animate homeflex">
  <img src="https://ocelot.lol/assets/icon.png" class="logo">
</div>
```

The first part of the animation is offset on mobile and I'm not sure why? The full code is [here](https://github.com/realHypnoticOcelot/ocelot.lol), but the error is still reproducible with the code I've provided. I've set the other items in the div to not display until the animation finishes, which is why there looks to be some unnecessary JS code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What specifically isn't working in the animation on mobile?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "mobile"? Is it a specific phone's browser that has the issue or smaller screen sizes?

Comment: The animation is pushing to the right. I’m using Chrome on IOS, but Chrome on desktop, even when using the inspect tool’s smaller screen sizes seems to work fine

Comment: Chrome on iOS is using Safari's rendering engine, so you're actually testing Safari WebKit. I can see the problem on an iPhone specifically.

Comment: If it's not something I can fix then it isn't a huge deal, but if there is any solution I'd love to know!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the crux of your issue on iOS is you're appending the logo in the DOM a 2nd time when the first animation completes. This causes a delay where the default "load" animation starts playing, then the "movecorner" animation kicks in shortly afterwards to override it.

So basically, reorganize your code to remove `html.appendChild(logo)` from the `animationend` event listener. Just adding the `movelogo` class should be sufficient to kick off the new animation.

```js
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.loadclass');
const html = document.querySelector('html')
const cornermenu = document.querySelector('.menu')
const root = document.documentElement
const a = document.querySelectorAll('#adddisp')

logo.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  logo.classList.add('movelogo')
  for (const adddisp of a) {
    adddisp.classList.add('adddisp');
    adddisp.classList.remove('dispnone');
  }
},
{ once: true }
);

function button() {
  for (const loadclass of buttons) {
    loadclass.classList.add('buttonload');
  }
}

/*/ irrelevant but this logs the ID of the key you pressed
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(key) {
  console.log(key.which)
})
/*/
```

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background-color: black;
}

.break {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    height: 0;
}

.flex {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    resize: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow: visible;
}

.homeflex {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.animate {
    animation: fadein ease 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.logo {
    width: 6vw;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: load ease 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 250ms;
    transition: 0.2s;
    min-width: 60px;
}

.movelogo {
    animation: movecorner ease 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes load {
    0%   {width: 0%; opacity: 1;}
    25%  {width: 30%; border-radius: 50%;}
    50%  {width: 30%; border-radius: 50%;}
    100% {width: 20%; border-radius: 10%; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes movecorner {
    0% {
        width: 20%;
        border-radius: 10%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        border-radius: 20%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 2%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://ocelot.lol/assets/icon.png" class="logo">
<div class="flex animate homeflex">
</div>
```

Comment: Removing the appendchild breaks it on the live site.

Comment: Yes, I had to reorganize the styles a bit. Check my code snippet on your phone, if it works, adapt it to your website.

Comment: Will yours work when there are other items within the flexbox?

Comment: I'm not recommending any other changes than don't append your logo a 2nd time to the DOM. That doesn't really have anything to do with styling, it's just the side effects of you doing so in your case caused animation and transition effects to play on top of each other.

Comment: I edited the answer, add the absolute positioning styles to your `logo` class, and have the logo outside of the flex container by default. Your Javascript was moving it outside of the container anyways.